# Handle error for request future calls in volley

Tags: error-handling, android-volley, synchronous

I am making **synchronous** api calls using **RequestFuture** provided by **Volley** library.
I need to handle error response when in case the **status** **code** is 4xx/500.

```
    try {
  JSONObject response = future.get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  // exception handling
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
  // exception handling
}
```

Now the error is caught by **ExecutionException** catch clause. How do I get **NetworkResponse** from this error.

How to override **onErrorListener** in the catch clause.

Answer (score 5):

Try this for grabbing the error from volley. Also just a note when preforming future requests you should use get with a timeout so your not waiting forever.

```
try
{
   JSONObject response = future.get(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
catch(InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex)
{
   //check to see if the throwable in an instance of the volley error
   if(ex.getCause() instanceof VolleyError)
   {
       //grab the volley error from the throwable and cast it back
       VolleyError volleyError = (VolleyError)ex.getCause();
      //now just grab the network response like normal
      NetworkResponse networkResponse = volleyError.networkResponse;
   }                          
}
catch(TimeoutException te)
{
   Log.e(TAG,"Timeout occurred when waiting for response");
}
```